# Problem with boost::intrusive_ptr

Tags: boost, vector, assign

There is a struct which contain intrusive_ptr field:

```
struct BranchFeedback : boost::counted_base {
  ...
  boost::intrusive_ptr<BPredState> theBPState;
};
```

There is another varibale which is defined as

```
std::vector< std::vector< BPredState > >           theFetchState;
```

Now I have instantiated an object

```
BranchFeedback theFeedback;
```

and want to assign theFetchState to that field

```
theFeedback.theBPState = theFetchState[anIndex][!anOne];
```

However compiler says some errors

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in theFeedback.theBPState = .....
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're passing in a BPredState, but [intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) only supports operator= for pointers to the contained type (or other intrusive_ptrs)

so you could write theBPState = &(theFetchState[anIndex][!anOne]); or get an pointer or iterator to the element and use that instead.